# How to have a shell script that unpacks several files when executed?

Tags: shell, heredoc

I would like to have several text files within my shell script file that unpack into a directory once the script is executed. I've been getting by with 'here-doc' solutions that look like this:

```
cat>myTextFile.txt<<'EOF'
My Content
EOF
```

However, my shell scripts are getting larger and are beginning to require more and more files to be unpacked. Basically, I am making a computational pipeline, and want to distribute it as a single shell script, but it needs to expand into several directories/subdirectories/files once run.

Thanks!

Comment: It's normal to distribute a tarball and have the user unpack it. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @glenn, thanks for the recommendation. Just to see if it is possible, I wanted to have a single file that could be executed to unpack, and have all files in place for the pipeline, without using tar

Comment: You seem to be reimplementing the `shar` command to some extent (although it sounds like your script does more than just unpack a few files).

Comment: I've never heard of `shar` but I am very interested. To the man page!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed in your script a uuencoded tar file and unpack it like this:

```
tar xf - <<EOF
The uuencoded tarball
EOF
```

You can encode the data this way:

```
$ tar cf - src_tree | compress | uuencode src_tree.tar.Z >your_here_doc
```

then paste the file `your_here_doc` where `'The uuencoded tarball'` line is now, something like this:

```
$ (echo tar cf - '<<EOF'; cat your_here_doc; echo EOF) >self_expanding_files.sh
```

Comment: I like this idea and see how it is unpacked, but how do I embed the unencoded tar file?

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a tar archive and then appending that as binary payload to your script. A really good tutorial can be found here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts

Other options include scripts like [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/) which do all of the work for you, making it easier to automate builds.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a combination of `find` and `cp` command? Something like this

`find /path/to/your/files -exec cp {} /destination/path \;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I would prefer to have the files somehow encapsulated in the bash script, as it needs to be distributed as a single file